# MYSQL - update a column from a SELECT result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the result in the column `count` from this query

```
SELECT `id_order`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `gf_order_detail`
GROUP BY `id_order`
```

to update the column `gf_comp.nbr`

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE `gf_comp`
SET `nbr` =
(
SELECT `id_order`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `gf_order_detail`
GROUP BY `id_order`)
WHERE gf_comp.ID=id_order;
```

But I get the error
#1054 - Unknown column 'id_order' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your where clause inside the subquery:

```
UPDATE `gf_comp` g
SET g.`nbr` =
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `gf_order_detail`
WHERE g.ID=id_order
GROUP BY `id_order`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join your query to `gf_comp`:

```
UPDATE gf_comp c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_order, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM gf_order_detail
  GROUP BY id_order
) o ON o.id_order = c.ID
SET c.nbr = o.count;
```